# Скрывающийся по клику блок

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть div с еще одним div(background-image:url(/plus.png)) и с сделать так чтобы под div-ы скрывались по клику и а div менялся на minus.png

Нашел решение,ну совсем простое :

```
var DecisionVar = {
            content : 'decisionContent_',
            toggle: function(elem, imgID){
                var id = $(elem).attr('cid');
                if($(elem).attr('tgl') == 0) {
                    $('#' + this.content + id).show();
                    $(elem).attr('tgl', 1);
                    $('#' + imgID).removeClass('menu_point_image_close').addClass('menu_point_image_open');
                }
                else {
                    $('#' + this.content + id).hide();
                    $(elem).attr('tgl', 0);
                    $('#' + imgID).removeClass('menu_point_image_open').addClass('menu_point_image_close');
                }

            }

        };
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно чту Вам нужно. Приведите пример Вашего кода.

Comment: Привел пример кода,это для diva скрывающего под div.
На этом divе есть div с у которого background-image:url(plus.png).
Хочется чтобы когда закрытый был,картинка + и все закрыто,а при клике открыто и картинка -.

Comment: Еще и разметку не помешало бы, а то задача простая, но Вы наворотили черти чего...

Comment: Согласен. Я в принципе и спрашивал HTML-код, а не JS

Comment: Сорри мое нубское не понимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мде... странный код, attr -> cid, tgl и прочие замуты))).

```
<div id="block">
  <div id="act" class="plus"></div>
  <div id="hide_or_show">Я прячусь и показываюсь</div>
</div>

$('#act').click(function() {
    if ($("#hide_or_show").is(':hidden')) {
        $("#hide_or_show").slideDown('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass('minus'); return false;
    } else {
       $('#hide_or_show').slideUp('fast');
       $(this).toggleClass('plus'); return false;
    }
});
```

Создать в css классы minus, plus и задать им нужный background.

Comment: $(this).toggleClass('minus plus')

Comment: На блоке на который кликаешь должно быть изображение изображение ,которое от положения должна меняться с + на - и наоборот.

Comment: Я внимательно читал вопрос! Дал исчерпывающий ответ!
Чутка подправил ход.

Comment: Спасибо,решение оказалось чуток проще.